# Unknown column in field list

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql-5.7, insert, mysql-workbench

Please help i dont know what i'm doing wrong.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `setState`(IN `statename` VARCHAR(100), IN `countryID` INT(11))
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
      SET @statename := `stateName`;
      SET @countryID := `country_idcountry`;

    INSERT INTO `state`(
        `stateName`,
        `country_idcountry`
    )
    SELECT    
        `stateName`,
        `country_idcountry`
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            @statename AS `stateName`,
            @countryID AS `country_idcountry`
    ) AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT
            stateName
        FROM
            state
        WHERE
            stateName = @statename
    )
    LIMIT 1;
END;
```

When i execute the statement with

```
call ccc.setState('Region Maritime', 8);
```

it returns

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'country_idcountry' in 'field list'
```

But my STATE Field is shown below :
[image]

the 'country_idcountry' is a foreign key from the country table.

Answer (score 1):

You In  para meter **is not** *country_idcountry* it **is** *countryID*

see

```
PROCEDURE `setState`(IN `statename` VARCHAR(100), IN `countryID` INT(11))
```

So you mus use

```
SET @countryID := `countryID`;
```

To grab the country_idcountry.

Be aware when country_idcountry is a foreign key you must have the county id already in your database.